# May I convert Schengen Business visa into work permit or freelance visa in Germany?

Tags: germany, work, schengen-visas

A German company wants to hire me as a freelancer and to invite me with Schengen Business visa to be in Germany for three months.

Can I convert my Business visa into a work permit or freelance visa locally in Germany or I must get back to my country and apply for a work visa in my country?

Comment: Hello user52791, you should ask questions about working in Germany in Expatriates SE, not in Travel SE. However, a company cannot **hire** you as a freelancer. Either they hire you as an employee or they contract with you as a freelancer. As an employee, you may qualify for a Blue Card work permit. As a freelancer, things are more complicated.

Comment: Additionally, the ability to get a residence permit if you hold a short-stay visamay depend on your citizenship. Please mention that when you post in [Expatriates.SE].